# PhoneGap Android: Input color and focus weird (with images!)

Tags: android, html, css, input, cordova

I have two problems around the input box of my PhoneGap HTML5 CSS3 app.

1) When I select or have "focus" on the input, the background of the input turns to the color white, and the text-color is black.

Is there some css property I have missed?

2) Now when I select of have "focus" on the input, on my Android, my keyboard comes up (ofc) so I can start writing text into the input field. The problem here is that when I press "Done" on my keyboard, the keyboard disapiers, however the input field is still selected/"focus" on.

Is this a bug?

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<style type="text/css">
    input, input:focus {
        background:lime;
    }   
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Heres two pictures from ANOTHER app. Same issue!

problem 1)

[image]

problem 2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your input field is changing colors because it's inheriting it's properties and colors from earlier in your code. The color of the DIV is not changing though.

If you want the input field to NOT change colors on focus then try something like:

```
input.txtSearchField:focus {
    background:#7AC9F0;
}
```

And that will make it the same color as your DIV behind the input field.

Comment: Just updated the question, still got problems :/
Feels like a phonegap error?

Comment: Technically speaking PhoneGap simply wraps a web page or web view (browser view), if you will, into an app. In theory it should use the same browser and engine the device uses by default. So if it looks correct in your device's default browser then it should look correct in PhoneGap as well. With the new code that you have edited in, if this isn't working for you then you could try something to the effect of 'input { background-color: lime; }'

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm not able to fix it with css. Not the :focus selector or the :active selector.
Is there maybe some other css trick.
I am also beginning to believe it's a phonegap/cordova bug